# Android navigation bar loses color on landscape

Tags: android, colors, navigation, navigationbar

I picked a navigation bar color and it works fine in portrait mood but when I switch to landscape it changes back to black, this is my style sheet

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkestGray</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/darkestGray</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>

</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this `getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.navigation_bar_color));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. We cannot set a color to navigation bar in landscape under lollipop. But we can set transpalent temporarily these version. You set the flag which is View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.

Comment: How can I set this flag?